# Property for BindingSource to return alphabetically sorted list

Tags: c#, linq, bindingsource

I'm trying to create a property that returns a `BindingSource` in alphabetical order, here by the column "Name". Below is a shot at using Linq, which doesn't compile: 'BindingSource does not contain a defintion for OrderBy'

I have no preference in how this is accomplished, Linq or otherwise.
What do you suggest?

```
internal System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource bsContractors;
this.bsContractors = new 
System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);

public System.Collections.Generic.List<Contractor> Contractors
{
    get
    { 
        // Linq
        List < Contractor > SortedList = bsContractors.OrderBy(o => o.Name).ToList();

        bsContractors.DataSource = SortedList;

        return bsContractors.List as System.Collections.Generic.List<Contractor>;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just guessing here, but try this:

```
 List <Contractor> SortedList = bsContractors.List.Cast<Contractor>().OrderBy(o => o.Name).ToList();
```